# Feedback on real estate ad design

Tags: page-layout, color-theory, critique

I am a Real Estate Agent with is looking to improve and differentiate myself from the competition. I am using Canva and realized that there is so much potential with good design.

1. Are the color choices right?
2. Are the sizes of the boxes done right?
3. Should I have used any other fonts?
4. Do you think that the amount of bedrooms, bathrooms, and the fact that it has a 1 car garage is converted through the ad design?

This is my most recent poster for a facebook ad, one is two weeks old and the other is from today. Want to see if I made improvements.

Also, I don't have any control over the plan.

[image]
[Click here for larger version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ghKA.png)

[image]
[Click here for larger version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmOmF.png)

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Yes you can get feedback for designs here, however you need to follow [the guidelines for critic questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work).  Just posting an image an asking for feedback alone is not enough.

Comment: Hi Billy, the thing is that I just started learning this skill. All the knowledge I have is self-taught. In my eyes it is perfect but I know it is not. I don't know what aspects it might have which are not good, I also don't know the jargon which would be needed to formulate the question. My profession is being a real estate agent.

Comment: When I walk out of the bathroom, can I fall down the spiral staircase?

Comment: Will the exhaust from the garage pollute the air and food in the adjacent kitchen area?

Comment: Hi @Stan, The plan is not my work, but work of a qualified architect commisioned by the owner. The staircase leads to another level within the property.

Comment: @PieBie Your edit made side-by-side comparison impossible which was requested by the OP. Somewhere between the original and your reduction is optimal

Comment: You can easily open each in a browser tab and compare them. The medium sizes provided by Imgur differed quite a lot, that's why I chose the small ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Are the color choices right?
> 2. Are the sizes of the boxes done right?
> 3. Should I have used any other fonts?
> 4. do you think that the amount of bedrooms, bathrooms, and the fact
>      that it has a 1 car garage is converted through the ad design?

In the *world of design*, as in any other profession there are priorities, and sometimes they have nothing to do with the most obvious ones, such as the ones you state in your question.

Graphic designers usually describe works with images:

[image]

My recommendation: try to see more in depth, as an example, design in black and white, this will allow you to see the mistakes more clearly.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will make sure to use this feedback and improve my skills.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is my personal opinion, feel free to disagree/ignore some or all of it.  Anyhoo, here is a rundown of my initial thoughts on your questions.

1. Not so keen on the colours in your second example, I think the first are better.  The dark blue in combination with the black icons doesn't work for me. Perhaps if the icons were white it would be better. It's important to think about contrast when using darker colours.
2. No.  The right edge of the box at the bottom in the second example should line up with the box above.  Also the boxes overlap the drawing slightly, I would make the drawing slightly smaller to avoid that, or even adjust the width of the boxes.
3. I'm not keen on the big bold font. It's just a little too big and bold, and I'm not so keen on the increased kerning between the letters, perhaps a bit less would be better.
4. I think the icons with the numbers below them are a good idea.

I can't tell which is the newer and older version.

Comment: Thank you Very much, I will definitely make improvements with this.

Comment: Thanks will differently use your suggestions and make improvements.